# Edit and delete from SQL database through Azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I have been building a Windows Phone 8 app and Windows Azure cloud service that will allow people to store schedules in the cloud. I have implemented a single sign on system and a cloud service used to store the schedule items.

I have however run into yet another problem, as I am using a cloud service to communicate with the database, the commands are slightly different, for example, this is the code to add a record to the database:

```
public bool addMedication(string userid, string medname, DateTime medtime)
    {
        using (var meds = new TMP_Meds_Entities())
        {
            meds.med_schedule.Add(new med_schedule()
            {
                userid = userid,
                medname = medname,
                medtime = medtime
            });

            meds.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I now need to implement methods to allow a user to edit or delete a particular record in the database, does anybody know how I might go about editing or deleting a record? As a note, I am using EntityFramework.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know windows phone, but it looks like you might be using EntityFramework? In which case standard EF commands should work. If that's right, I'll post some examples.

Comment: Yes I'm using EntityFramework, I forgot to mention! I'll edit the original question so its more clear, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less from scratch, so you'll need to adapt it to your scenario, but this should get you started...

Update:

```
public void UpdateMed(meds med)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.meds.Attach(med);
        db.Entry(med).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Delete:

```
public void DeleteMed(int medid)
{
   meds med = db.meds.Find(medid);
   db.meds.Remove(med);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here are a couple good resources for more detail

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=619

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with an Azure cloud service. To be honest, editing and deleting database data through Azure seems to be largely undocumented, but there must be a way of doing it?